# What is the principle behind user login verification implemented by session and sessionID?

Tags: session

When studying "User Login Implementation Based on Session," most blog posts only provide a brief explanation that after a user logs in, the backend generates a unique session ID and stores it in a cookie on the user's browser. Any authenticated operations performed by the user after logging in will first send the session ID back to the backend for verification.

However, there are hardly any blog posts that explain how the backend identifies the corresponding user and performs verification based on the session ID, as well as the deeper knowledge about sessions. These articles typically offer relatively superficial explanations based on the application layer and fail to provide a clear understanding of how the backend actually implements the verification of the session ID returned by the user and matches it with the corresponding session information at the session's underlying level.

I would like to obtain the answer to this question from a theoretical perspective, without focusing on specific language implementations. However, if necessary, I would appreciate it if the respondent could provide an explanation using the HttpSession version of Java Spring Boot as an example.